# Echos not working

Tags: php, cakephp, echo

I am trying to make a site using cakephp and twitter bootsrap. For the gallery I am making I am trying to display, using foreach, multiple images , but they simply don't show up. Everything is working, the foreach and the variable data, but the echos don't display anything. Could anyone help please? 
Thanks in advance.
(code bellow from my show_images.ctp view)

```
    <table >
<tr>

<?php
$i=0;
foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
<td align=center>
  <?php echo "<a id=\"single_1\" href=\"test/".$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path']." ";?>
  <?php echo "<img src=\"test/".$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'].", alt=\"".$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path']."";?>
  <?php echo "</a>";?>

    </td>
    <?php $i++;?>

    <?php
        if($i==4){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: You're not closing your `a` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't close your tag inside echo
try to change this:

```
<?php echo "<a id=\"single_1\" href=\"test/".$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path']." ";?>
  <?php echo "<img src=\"test/".$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'].", alt=\"".$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path']."";?>
  <?php echo "</a>";?>
```

to this:

```
<?php echo '<a id="single_1" href="test'.$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'].' >';?>
  <?php echo '<img src="test'.$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'].'" alt="'.$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'].'" />';?>
  <?php echo '</a>';?>
```